# Restoring model database from another DB backup

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am trying to change the data in the model database. Given that the relationships in there are complex I can only achieve change by pointing my application to a database e.g. model_application, and making changes via the UI.

Then I backup the model_application database and simply want to use that as my model, this is not possible as I keep getting the error "The system database cannot be moved by Restore".

I don't want to:

1. Use export/import data
2. Make the changes manually
3. Cannot point application to model database either

Can anyone please help?

Comment: By "model database" do you mean the intrinsic system `model` database?

Comment: I'm curious why you have anything custom in `model`, it is meant exclusively for the system's use. Users should never have any objects, tables, relationships, or anything to do with that table.

Comment: Yes the system model database. Hmm, that's a strange comment, model database is designed so you can customise it.  New databases get all their tables and data from that database which is what I am using it for!

Comment: my apologies, I was thinking you were talking about the `master` database. Whoops!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be you're trying to restore the backup over the existing model database? That would explain the error you're getting.

Because the following should work:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [model_copy] 
FROM  DISK = N'F:\model.bak' 
WITH  FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'modeldev' TO N'F:\model_copy.mdf',  
MOVE N'modellog' TO N'F:\model_copy_1.ldf'
GO
```

Comment: Not quite, I actually want to RESTORE DATABASE [model] from model_application.bak.  As mentioned before I get the error "The system database cannot be moved by RESTORE."